# Silverlight service callback returns null

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to get data with the methods below and I get null response and can't figure out why. I'm just trying out a different way of using a wcf service from silverlight and I don't understand something that I should. I wish someone will see what is going wrong here :)

This is my service agent class:

```
Private Shared m_service As New DataServiceClient

    Public Shared Sub GetSiteLogin(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String, callback As System.EventHandler(Of GetSiteLoginCompletedEventArgs))
            AddHandler m_service.GetSiteLoginCompleted, callback
            m_service.GetSiteLoginAsync(user, pass)
        End Sub
```

This is the call:

```
Dim em As New DataService.Employee
                Dim pass As String = CustomSecurity.Hash.GetSHA1Hash(txtPassword.Password)

                ' Try to get the employee with the login information
                SettingsServiceAgent.GetSiteLogin(txtUsername.Text, pass, Sub(s, r) em = r.Result)
```

The employee object will stay null. If I put a break into the service call and follow through the code it finds the correct record from the database and the return statement shows an object with the correct data but still the employee object in silverlight side will remain null.

Some help please :) And thanks!

Comment: Have you tried firing up Fiddler or Developer tools and capturing the request? Does the response body have what you're looking for?

Comment: Both are new subjects for me but I'll try to look into those. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Toughed I would answer my own question. I found out that the service is returning a value to me but I failed to fully understand the nature of async calls. What I am trying to accomplish is coding that feels synchronous while actually being async if that makes any sense. So the employee object is null because I don't have any knowledge that the service has returned something in the agent class. I would still need a method to tell me when the employee object is ready to be used. This would have to be some sort of event maybe PropertyChanged or a custom event but anyway I will need to stop the code, wait for the employee to have the value I need and then continue. Don't know how to accomplish this in the same block of code without jumping to an event handler etc...

Any ideas or links for me to read are appreciated.